# Saving related data to the database via stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and currently trying to find out an efficient way of saving related data to a SQL Server database. I know Entity Framework does this for you easily, but unfortunately we are using stored procedures in our application to store and retrieve data to the database.That being said we call the SP's in out code via EF. To cut the story short, we use only SPs in EF and not tables

I am trying to store request, services, worklog and activities data to the database. At a time I would be storing only one request. Each request would contain one or more services, activities or worklog. One service would contain one or more activities or worklog. One activity would contain one or more worklogs.

My initial thought was to first save the request data and generate and requestid. Pass that request id to the services and so on. The only issue with this approach is that there are multiple postbacks.

I want to minimise this approach my generating temporary ids and linking the data. Could somebody share a working example and suggest a better approach

Comment: I don't know where to start... why the heck would you choose to use Stored Procedures for saving/loading data ?  As for "share a working example", I think the idea is that you should show us the code you've written and we'll  suggest improvements.  (Which will probably include the phrase "Keep it simple... Use Entity Framework instead...")

Comment: Hey Mike. I agree with you on this. Unfortunately the company prefers to have more control over the  database and hence this approach. I wish I had a some directions to start with and hence dont have any working code

Comment: Guide to calling sps. http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson07 and you might need to wrap it in a transaction. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522039/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-Transaction I have more often worked with sps than EF in my career. But I am a) old and b) quite backend heavy in terms of skills... c) not always keen on huge frameworks like EF. (but see a!) :-)

Comment: Just to be clear we arent using ADO.Net. We fire SPs via EF.

Comment: Why you use stored procs? Because they are better for security since you do not have to give any rights at the table or view level and thuius people can only do what is in the  stored proc which is vetted code. They are better for complex operations and they are often faster than the convoluted code  Entity Framework writes and they are much easier to performance tune.

Comment: The reason why they use storedprocedures in this organisation is because the people who are supporting this application are having sound database background as compared to .Net and would like complete control of the CRUD operations. It would be easier for them to troubleshoot issues in case of production problems

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you put everything in a transaction so that it rolls back if there is a problem at any one step. You do the insert to the parent table and use the output clause to get the id for the record and then use that id in the inserts to any child tables. If your company is exclusively using stored procs, there must be some examples of how they did this for other parent child relationships.

Comment: This is their first MVC 5 application. Most of their other applications are outsourced or doing simple operations